# How do I change the text cut off for input text forms?

Tags: html, css

How do I change the text cut off for an input form? I tried adding a "padding-right" tag to the css, but it changed the whole form's style, rather than just the [type=text] style. Sorry if this is rather vague, I have no clue what it's called.

This is how long the text cut off is, I want to extend it, but I have no idea how.

[image]

Here's the CSS code:

```
.title-input-style {
    padding-right: 15vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 1vh;
    border:none;
    border: 2px solid #47d680;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #dbffea;
}

.title-input-style::placeholder {
    font-size: large;
    padding-right: 15vh;
}

.title-input-style:focus {
    background-color: #c7ffde;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #47d680;
}

.title-input-style[type=text] {
    font-size: large;
    padding-left: 1vh;
}
```

Comment: Plz include the html.

Answer (score 0):

Text inputs have a set width/height and will just hide the overflow content inside of it. A textarea will add scrollbars if you extend past it's height. You can set the `rows` and `cols` parameter on a textarea as well. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp. Perhaps that is what you're looking for.

```css
.title-input-style {
    padding-right: 1vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    padding-bottom: 1vh;
    border:none;
    border: 2px solid #47d680;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #dbffea;
    width: 99%;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.title-input-style::placeholder {
    font-size: large;
    padding-right: 15vh;
}

.title-input-style:focus {
    background-color: #c7ffde;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #47d680;
}

.title-input-style[type=text] {
    font-size: large;
    padding-left: 1vh;
}

.title-input-style {
```

```html
<input type="text" class="title-input-style">

<textarea type="text" class="title-input-style" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```